# How do I set the foreground color of any child element in a Grid from the Grid's style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

How do I set the `Foreground` color of all child elements in a `Grid` from within the Grid's Style? I know I've done this before, but I can't remember where or how.

```
<Style x:Key="MyGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    // I want to set the font color here
</Style>

<Grid Style="{StaticResource MyGridStyle}">
    ...
</Grid>
```

I know I can use

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

however I want to set this value in the `Style`, not in the `Grid`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Figured it out, I just need to set the default style in `<Style.Resources>`

```
<Style x:Key="MyGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 18):

How about:

```
<Style x:Key="MyGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: That works, but only for TextBlocks. Using `<Style.Resources>` lets me style `TextBoxes` and other controls as well. +1 anyways for a cleaner way of doing it if your panel only contains `TextBlock` elements

Comment: lol yes, I was testing with `TextBlock` elements but my actual Grid contains `TextBoxes` as well. I didn't think to make the distinction until you posted your answer :)

Comment: It solved my problem when I tried to apply `Foreground` for all children inside a `Border` control.