# UWP Xaml : Container style that applies to children

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

Let say I want to style a grid background like that :

```
<Page.Resources>
   <Style x:key="MainGridStyle" TargetType="Grid">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
   </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

How can I make all TextBlocks inside that MainGridStyle `Foreground=White` through that Style?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197667/how-do-i-set-the-foreground-color-of-any-child-element-in-a-grid-from-the-grids

Comment: Its not duplicate... That applies to WPF, not UWP! (unfortunately)

Comment: Can you try @Rachel answer on the link? Hope it works for you

Comment: Yeah I tried, but Style.Resources is not valid in UWP

Comment: In UWP, you would have to create a new `<Style/>` for  it's children elements.

Answer (score 0):

This works in WPF at least:

```
<Style x:key="MainGridStyle" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Interesting... but unfortunately it does not work with UWP project :(

Comment: I guess you will have to define a separate TextBlock style in <Grid.Resources> then.

Comment: @mm8: it hasn't been answered...he asked about uwp, the supplied answer was about wpf